# Given a set of binary trees, select a subset such that it covers all the trees

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have a set of binary trees. I need to find a minimal subset of them such that it covers all the trees. By cover I mean, if there is a tree A and a tree B such that B is a subtree of A, then A covers B. By minimal subset I mean, out of all the subsets that can cover all the trees, we need the one that has the smallest size (size = number of trees in that set).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1) Sort trees by number of nodes. Start with the one with fewest nodes.

2) build a tree comparer that takes two graphs of your data-structure. This comparer should first iterate the larger of the two trees (recursively) looking for the top node in the lesser tree. If found: iterate side by side until difference is found (NO MATCH) or to the end of the lesser tree(MATCH)

3) Compare the smalles tree to the other trees until first MATCH or until all other trees have been compared to. (Start comparing agains the tree you think is most likly to be a match). If no Match: That tree has to be in your subset. If match: Discard the current tree as it is represented in another tree.

4) Compare the second smalles tree to all larger graphs etc..